# How to add custom text to primeng paginator

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng

I would like to know if you can add custom text to the paginator row, more specifically, i would like it to have the total hits for the table on the right.

Comment: Hey, I also need to add a text around row-count (eg: Show [5] entries). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 11):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorright">
  {{totalRecords}}
</ng-template>
```

and if you want to show page rows range then you can add like this,

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft">
  Showing {{totalRecords < 1 ? 0 : first + 1}} to 
  {{totalRecords > 0 ? ((rows+ first) <= totalRecords ? (rows + first) : 
  totalRecords) : 0}} of {{totalRecords ? totalRecords : 0}} entries  
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add it manually below the table...

```
<p-dataTable
    #myCoolTable>
...
</p-dataTable>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; right: 20px;">
    filtered {{ myCoolTable.totalRecords }} from a total count of {{ myCoolTable.value.length }}
</div>
```

where totalEntriesCount is set by the component upon fetching the data from the server...

Remember to move the style stuff to your scss/less/css! ;)

Edit: The unfiltered data count is also stored in the length of the value.
It might be that the table is not accessible from outside, so you can declare it as a `ViewChild('myCoolTable') myCoolTable;` in the component.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add the custom text inside the Paginator row. But you can add the total hit just below the paginator using footer inside the table as

```
<p-footer>Total Hits:{{totalHits}}</p-footer>
```

Otherwise you can add the total hit above the paginator by making paginator seperate, for example

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [paginator]="false">....
<p-column field="Col1" header="Column 1"><p-column>
<p-footer>total Hits: {{totalHits}}</p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
<p-paginator rows="10" totalRecords="120" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]"></p-paginator>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact solution for adding custom text or total rows count on paginator for primeng datatable (angular):

```
<p-dataTable 
     [value]="myRecords"
     rows="10"                             
     [pageLinks]="5"
     [paginator]="false"
     [lazy]="true"
     [totalRecords]="totalRecordsCount"
     (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)"
     [responsive]="true">

<p-column field="" header="test"></p-column>                                         
</p-dataTable>


<div style="position: relative;">
    <p-paginator rows="10"
         (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)"
         (onPageChange)="loadData($event)"
         [totalRecords]="totalRecordsCount"
         [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25]">
    </p-paginator>
    <span style="position: absolute; top:3px; right:5px; margin: 5px;">Total records: {{totalRecordsCount}} </span>
</div>
```